# How to fix the display of the table using PHP and html

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, html-table

I have a code that display the fetched data in a table using **foreach loop** with if statement to check if the field is empty or not   but the problem is that  the table is displaying on each row the field name.

How to fix the display? I will appreciate any help I know that the error is in the foreach loop.

[image: each row includes the field name and the value.... take a look]
 after using the answer of Doomenik

[image]

## code:

```
 $sql = $wpdb->prepare("select i.siteID
         , i.siteNAME
         , i.equipmentTYPE
         , c.latitude
         , c.longitude
         , c.height 
         , o.ownerNAME
         , o.ownerCONTACT
         , x.companyNAME
         , y.subcontractorCOMPANY
         , y.subcontractorNAME
         , y.subcontractorCONTACT
      from site_info i
      LEFT  
      JOIN owner_info o
        on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
      LEFT  
      JOIN company_info x
        on i.companyID = x.companyID
      LEFT 
      JOIN subcontractor_info y
        on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
        LEFT JOIN site_coordinates2 c
        on i.siteID=c.siteID 
        where 
        i.siteNAME = %s
        AND 
        o.ownerID = %d
        AND 
        x.companyID = %d
       ",$site_name,$owner_name,$company_name);

     $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);

    echo "<table class='t1' width='30%'> ";
  echo     "<tr>";
  echo           "<th>Site ID</th>";
  echo           "<th>Site Name</th>";

  if(!empty($query_submit->latitude)) { 
     echo "<th>Lattitude</th>";


  } else { echo '<th></th>'; } 



  if(!empty($query_submit->longitude)){ 
     echo "<th>Longitude</th>";


  } else { echo '<th></th>'; } 

  echo "<th>Owner Name</th>";

  if(!empty($query_submit->ownerCONTACT))
  { 
     echo "<th>Owner Contact</th>";


  } else { echo '<th></th>'; } 
  echo           "<th>Company Name</th>";
  if(!empty($query_submit->equipmentTYPE)){ 
     echo "<th>Equipment Type</th>";


  } else { echo '<th></th>'; } 

  if(!empty($query_submit->height)) { 
     echo "<th>Height</th>";


  } else { echo '<th></th>'; } 

  if(!empty($query_submit->subcontractorCONTACT)){ 
     echo "<th>Sub Contact</th>";


  } else { echo '<th></th>'; } 


  if(!empty($query_submit->subcontractorCOMPANY)) { 
     echo "<th>Sub company Name</th>";
  } else { echo '<th></th>'; } 
  echo   "</tr>";
  foreach ($query_submit as $obj) {
    echo   "<tr>";   
    echo         "<td>".$obj->siteID."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->siteNAME."</td>";
    if(!empty($obj->latitude)) { 
         echo "<td>".$obj->latitude."</td>";
    } else { echo '<td></td>'; } 


    if(!empty($obj->longitude)) { 
        echo "<td>".$obj->longitude."</td>";
    } else { echo '<td></td>'; } 

    echo "<td>".$obj->ownerNAME."</td>";
    if(!empty($obj->ownerCONTACT)) { 
        echo "<td>".$obj->ownerCONTACT."</td>";
    } else { echo '<td></td>'; } 

    echo "<td>".$obj->companyNAME."</td>";
    if(!empty ($obj->equipmentTYPE)){ 
        echo "<td>".$obj->equipmentTYPE."</td>";
    } else { echo '<td></td>'; } 

    if(!empty($obj->height)){ 
        echo "<td>".$obj->height."</td>";
    } else { echo '<td></td>'; } 

    if(!empty($obj->subcontractorCONTACT)){ 
        echo "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCONTACT."</td>";
    } else { echo '<td></td>'; } 


    if(!empty($obj->subcontractorCOMPANY)){ 
        echo "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY."</td>";
    } else { 
        echo '<td></td>'; 
    } 
    echo "</tr>";
}
 echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** Removed cause of new Informations provided *

Basicly I moved the creation of the th in front of the for each, otherwise you would create every loop this line. So this one will create first the "" row and then create inside the for each every data line. You can see directly under the for each, I open a "" and close it at the end of the loop. After everything finished I close the table.

**EDIT 3:**
Here is know the solution for your situation, cause I dont have so much times its a very quick and dirty one. There is much potential to improve it, but this will be up to you

```
echo "<table class='t1' width='30%'> ";
echo     "<tr>";
echo           "<th>Site ID</th>";
echo           "<th>Site Name</th>";

//First we gonna check which columns contain at least 1 value
$latitude = false;
$longitude = false;
$ownerCONTACT = false;
$equipmentTYPE = false;
$height = false;
$subcontractorCONTACT = false;
$subcontractorCOMPANY = false;

foreach ($query_submit as $header_obj) {
    //If only one cel in the column has an value we put his variable to true
    if(!empty($header_obj->latitude)) {
        $latitude = true;
    }
    if(!empty($header_obj->longitude)) {
        $longitude = true;
    }
    if(!empty($header_obj->ownerCONTACT)) {
        $ownerCONTACT = true;
    }
    if(!empty($header_obj->equipmentTYPE)) {
        $equipmentTYPE = true;
    }
    if(!empty($header_obj->height)) {
        $height = true;
    }
    if(!empty($header_obj->subcontractorCONTACT)) {
        $subcontractorCONTACT = true;
    }
    if(!empty($header_obj->subcontractorCOMPANY)) {
        $subcontractorCOMPANY = true;
    }
}

//Now we check and if there is content we place the th
if($latitude === true) {
    echo "<th>Lattitude</th>";
}

if($longitude === true){
    echo "<th>Longitude</th>";
}

echo "<th>Owner Name</th>";

if($ownerCONTACT === true) {
    echo "<th>Owner Contact</th>";
}

echo "<th>Company Name</th>";

if($equipmentTYPE === true){
    echo "<th>Equipment Type</th>";
}

if($height === true) {
    echo "<th>Height</th>";
}

if($subcontractorCONTACT === true){
    echo "<th>Sub Contact</th>";
}

if($subcontractorCOMPANY === true) {
    echo "<th>Sub company Name</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";

//Here we loop again trough the obj, we write now every row.
//If we had an empty column (so also no head) we will skip that value.
foreach ($query_submit as $obj) {
    echo   "<tr>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->siteID."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->siteNAME."</td>";

    if($latitude === true) {
        //In this situation the column exists but we dont know if the specific cell has 
        // a value so we check this here
        if(!empty($obj->latitude)) {
            echo "<td>".$obj->latitude."</td>";
        } else {
            //If it doesnt has one we make at least an empty cell so the layout gets not broken
            echo "<td></td>";
        }
    }

    if($longitude === true){
        if(!empty($obj->longitude)) {
            echo "<td>".$obj->longitude."</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td></td>";
        }
    }

    echo "<td>".$obj->ownerNAME."</td>";

    if($ownerCONTACT === true) {
        if(!empty($obj->ownerCONTACT)) {
            echo "<td>".$obj->ownerCONTACT."</td>";
        } else {
            echo '<td></td>';
        }
    }

    echo "<td>".$obj->companyNAME."</td>";

    if($equipmentTYPE === true){
        if(!empty ($obj->equipmentTYPE)){
            echo "<td>".$obj->equipmentTYPE."</td>";
        } else {
            echo '<td></td>';
        }
    }

    if($height === true) {
        if(!empty($obj->height)){
            echo "<td>".$obj->height."</td>";
        } else { echo '<td></td>'; }
    }

    if($subcontractorCONTACT === true){
        if(!empty($obj->subcontractorCONTACT)){
            echo "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCONTACT."</td>";
        } else {
            echo '<td></td>';
        }
    }

    if($subcontractorCOMPANY === true) {
        if(!empty($obj->subcontractorCOMPANY)){
            echo "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY."</td>";
        } else {
            echo '<td></td>';
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: i tried your answer it did not work it just display the first result in the table and all the rest was out

Comment: Yeah after seeing your image I understood your problem give me a moment

Comment: i need to check if the table head doesn't have value i do not want to be displayed

Comment: Now I´m again confused, could you tell us how it should look like. Do you want in each row a head ? Only in the first row or no head ?

Comment: i need to display just the first time the field name like site id then under it all the value that are selected without having to display each time the field name

Comment: i need  to display the header only in the first row

Comment: @Dany7elo here you go

Comment: @ Doomenik i tired your answer it did not work check the image that i upload it

Comment: @Dany7elo I changed it, so the cels after the th should work. Th missing th, results because it only checks once if there is data. If you want me to go further a example of your query_submit would be not bad.

Comment: i will edit my answer and add the query with the result of your answer
the result display only the header table that don't includes if statement

Comment: Working like I expected. You want now that the rows without content wouldn´t be displayed. This is on many different ways possible. One would be to loop twice and check first the content. Another would be working with css and the display property. Anyway every solution, takes a while to write and probably I would need to run some tests. So I give you now the most ugly/quick solution I can provide.

Answer (score 1):

your th tags depends on $obj which can be different each time in loop.
so to overcome this what you can do is make the table header static and table row values will be blank or value depending on your $obj variable.
so you need to move out you

```
<table class='t1' width='30%'>
<tr>
<th>Site ID</th>
<th>Site Name</th>
// all th tags
</tr>
 <?php foreach ($query_submit as $obj) { // then foreach 
  echo   "<tr>";   
  echo         "<td>".$obj->siteID."</td>";
  echo         "<td>".$obj->siteNAME."</td>";
   ?><td><?php if(!empty($obj->latitude))
  {  echo $obj->latitude;} ?></tr>  // your td will be fixed contain of td will depend on your value.
  echo "<td>".$obj->siteID."</td>"; // and so on
```

To get your table html right here is an example of basic html table using foreach loop .
hope this will help you.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>heading 1</th>
 <th>heading 2</th>
<th>heading 3</th>
<th>heading 4</th>
<th>heading 5</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($array as $data){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php if(!empty($data->data1))  { echo $data->data1; } ?></td>
<td><?php if(!empty($data->data2))  { echo $data->data2; } ?></td>
<td><?php if(!empty($data->data3))  { echo $data->data3; } ?></td>
<td><?php if(!empty($data->data4))  { echo $data->data4; } ?></td>
<td><?php if(!empty($data->data5))  { echo $data->data5; } ?></td>
</tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp, the problem lies  in that you're iterating the headers in the loop, when they're only supposed to be called one time at the start of the table tag.
 I.e only the  tags should be looped/iterated through and take the  header tags out of the for each.

Comment: i know that i am iterating the header but i need this because not all the header have values so the empty one i don't want to be displayed

Comment: Ah alright i see, then you've got to debug and check why those if statements are still adding the header, perhaps the value seems empty to you but it actually isnt, for example an empty string " " might be returned and that will actually pass as true in if statement, because its length is 1